# IE9 problems - Appears that my slider won't even slide. What gives?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-9, anythingslider

I've got a site up at [www.alexjamesfraser.com](http://www.alexjamesfraser.com). It's using the Anythingslider jquery plugin big time. It works well enough under the latest versions of firefox and chrome but under IE9, the slider appears not to work at all. I have no idea why this is so and was hoping I could get some help here.

So, that's my question. I wish I could be more specific, but I'm sort of at a loss to even understand what I've done wrong. Hopefully some one can help and if you need any more information from me, please do not hesitate to ask.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had to dig a bit, but I see the problem now. When AnythingSlider is initialized, it's on an empty list (I don't think `</li>` is really valid either, leave it empty or use `<li/>`):

```
<ul class="slider" id="slider1">
    </li>
</ul>
```

which is fine, but then in the initialization callback, the current page is undefined because there are no pages:

```
onInitialized: function(e, slider1) {
    updateCaption1(slider1); 
}
```

caption function:

```
var updateCaption1 = function(slider1){
    // slider1.$currentPage is undefined because there are no slides!
    var cap = slider1.$currentPage.find('.caption1').html();
    $('.current-caption1')
        .html(cap)
        .fadeIn(200);
};
```

The `slider1.$currentPage` is undefined, and even the `slider1.currentPage` value is zero.

So, either remove the `onInitialized` functions, or update the caption after the slider gets updated with content.

Comment: I tried what you said and still have problems, sorry. The float </li> is gone and I stripped out the onInitialized functions too, but it's still problematic. Thanks for trying though. Are you one of the main developers on the Anything Slider. I know I've seen that avatar associated with it before. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I'm one of the guys that works on AnythingSlider ;)... Hmm, well IE9 seems to be working, but I do see a problem with the video extension. You've got multiple sliders with video and the extension is numbering the videos all the same. So the second set of videos aren't pausing... is that want you were talking about? Or is there something else going on that I'm missing.

Comment: No, that wasn't what I was talking about, but I've managed to fix my original problem is fixed now. The problem that you mention though, do you know how I would fix that? I appreciate your help. Thank you.